Native Hook using java.lang.foreign in JDK23
I wanted to try using NativeHook, which can be written entirely in Java, instead of JNativeHook, so I wrote some test code.
However, the output is always the same no matter which key I press.
Can someone tell me how to get the correct key code?
import java.lang.foreign.*;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class hook_test {
    private static final int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private static final int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static long hook;
    private static MethodHandle callNextHookEx;

    void main() throws Throwable {
        System.loadLibrary("user32");
        Linker linker = Linker.nativeLinker();
        SymbolLookup user32Lookup = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup();
        MethodHandle setWindowsHookEx = linker.downcallHandle(user32Lookup.find("SetWindowsHookExA").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT));
        callNextHookEx = linker.downcallHandle(user32Lookup.find("CallNextHookEx").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG));
        MethodHandle getMessage = linker.downcallHandle(user32Lookup.find("GetMessageA").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.ADDRESS, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT));
        MethodHandle unhookWindowsHookEx = linker.downcallHandle(user32Lookup.find("UnhookWindowsHookEx").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG));
        MethodHandle hookProcHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().findStatic(hook_test.class, "hookProc", MethodType.methodType(long.class, int.class, long.class, long.class));
        MemorySegment hookProcAddress = linker.upcallStub(hookProcHandle, FunctionDescriptor.of(ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_INT, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG, ValueLayout.JAVA_LONG), Arena.ofAuto());
        hook = (long) setWindowsHookEx.invoke(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProcAddress, MemorySegment.NULL, 0);

        if (hook == 0) {
            System.out.println("Failed to set hook");
            return;
        }

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                if (hook != 0)
                    unhookWindowsHookEx.invoke(hook);

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                System.err.println(t.getMessage());
            }
        }));
        try (Arena arena = Arena.ofAuto()) {
            MemorySegment msg = arena.allocate(28);
            while ((int) getMessage.invoke(msg, MemorySegment.NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static long hookProc(int code, long wParam, long lParam) {
        if (code >= 0) {
            if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
                System.out.printf("int code:%s\tlong wParam:%s\tlong lParam:%s\n", code, wParam, lParam);

        }
        try {
            return (long) callNextHookEx.invoke(hook, code, wParam, lParam);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.err.println(t.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

I expected that even if the correct key code was not obtained, a different value would be output from lParam for each key input. However, when I tried to run it, all the values ​​were the same and they changed every time I launched it.
int code:0  long wParam:256 long lParam:1059701387608
int code:0  long wParam:256 long lParam:1059701387608
int code:0  long wParam:256 long lParam:1059701387608
int code:0  long wParam:256 long lParam:1059701387608


Isn't the lParam just a pointer to a structure - it might be using a structure allocated for the lifetime of the hook just changing the values in the structure each time (I don't know this API so am just going by the doc.)

That may be true. I'll try some more. Thank you.

As greg-449 suggested in his comment, the two parameters shouldn't be longs. This is what my MinGW includes show:
typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK *HOOKPROC)(int code,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

typedef UINT_PTR WPARAM;
typedef LONG_PTR LPARAM;

In other words - one is a pointer to an int, the other a pointer to a long. In your code you should use MemoryLayout as types, and get their int and long values.

Note that LRESULT also isn't a long, it's a pointer to a long:
typedef LONG_PTR LRESULT;

That means you have to change the return type of both callNextHookEx and hookProc. The latter can return the MemorySegment returned by callNextHookEx or MemorySegment.NULL on failure.

Thank you! I'll try again when I get home.
